# tr changes file encoding?

Tags: linux, bash, tr

I have an UTF-8 encoded text file containing a listing of names. I'm trying to make separate files for the consonants and the vowels and I managed with simple `tr -d list-of-vowels`, but for some reason the resulting file replaced ç with xA7 and it further gets replaced by § when I run the file through a sed script (and messes up the script in the process hence the issue). All the signs in the file (I've converted it to all lower case for ease of analysis):
bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzçðñ àáâãæèéêëìíîïòóôõøúüýaeiouyäåö '*,-./`#

For some reason only ç causes problems. The `sed` I'm using to calculate the number of each character by year in the file is `sed -E -e 's/"([^"]*)","([^"]*)",.*/\L\2,\1/' -e 's/^([^,]+),(.)(.+)$/\1,\2\n\1,\3/; P; D'` but I don't think there should be a problem with it.

The file under processing is a .csv file formatted:

```
"hanna","1919","2"  
"hanna","1919","2"  
"heidi","1919","2"  
"heidi","1919","2"  
"anja","1938","2"  
"anja","1938","2"  
"eila","1947","2"  
"eila","1947","2"
```

Ordered first by year and then alphabetically.

Any clue on why `tr` is doing that and how to make it stop? I even tried to run `sed -i "s/\ｧ/\ç/g"` but it didn't actually do anything. Yet ｧ is how e.g. `cat` parses the bugged character.

Comment: (1) Which vendor's implementation of `tr`? (2) What was the value of `LC_CTYPE` (or `LC_ALL`)?; if you don't know that value, run the command `locale` and see its output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of `tr` from GNU coreutils (8.29) does not support UTF-8.

One [bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20114) suggests this is on the roadmap for version 9.

In the mean time, use `sed`.